# How to exclude a specific element in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to work with a random name from my_dict , except for the name "name300000.&**" , I want to skip it and pass to another name when choice(my_dict.values()) = "name300000.&**".
So I did the following, but I am looking for a better solution ?

```
from random import choice
my_dict = {1: "name1", 2: "name2", 3:"name300000.&**", 4:"name4"}
if "name3" in choice(my_dict.values()):
    pass
name = choice(my_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```py
name = choice(tuple(set(my_dict.values()) - {"name300000.&**"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
from random import choice
my_dict = {1: "name1", 2: "name2", 3:"name300000.&**", 4:"name4"}

name = choice(list(my_dict.values()))
while name == "name300000.&**":
    name = choice(my_dict.values())

print(name)
```

Or, another possible solution is:

```
from random import choice
my_dict = {1: "name1", 2: "name2", 3:"name300000.&**", 4:"name4"}


while True:
    name = choice(list(my_dict.values()))
    if name != "name300000.&**":
        break

print(name)
```

The point is that you have to emulate a do while loop to correctly solve this problem, and in python, since it is not natively present, you can write in these ways.

Comment: @adirabargil well python does not have natively the construct do while...

Comment: Lol sorry... my bad!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use set difference function to remove unwanted values:

```
from random import choice
my_dict = {1: "name1", 2: "name2", 3:"name300000.&**", 4:"name4"}
name = choice(list(set(my_dict.values()).difference({"name300000.&**"})))
```